# Why IAR throw error on void*

Tags: c, void, iar

I want to port a project using gcc to IAR compiler, but IAR complains on several functions using void* as formal parameter.

```
 struct 
 {
    uint16_t ConnectionHandle;
    uint8_t  Reason;
 }DisconnectParams;
```

the function prototype is

```
bool Bluetooth_HCI_SendControlPacket(BT_StackConfig_t* const StackState,
                                     const uint16_t OpCode,
                                     const uint8_t Length,
                                     const void* Data);
```

and the using is:

```
Bluetooth_HCI_SendControlPacket(StackState, (OGF_LINK_CONTROL | OCF_LINK_CONTROL_DISCONNECT), sizeof(DisconnectParams), &DisconnectParams);
```

Here complain
Error[Pe167]: argument of type "struct  *" is incompatible with parameter of type "void const *"

And another place

```
static inline void SDP_WriteData8(void** BufferPos,const uint8_t Data)
{
*((uint8_t*)*BufferPos) = Data;
*BufferPos += sizeof(uint8_t);
}
```

Error[Pe852]: expression must be a pointer to a complete object type. 
As I know, void* can accept any pointer,How to change the code to remove these errors? Thanks!

Chris

Comment: Can you supply more details about your IAR version and project settings? I cannot replicate your first problem with IAR 5.40.

Comment: My IAR is EWARM 6.30.1,setting is C99 and allow VLA(variable length array),but the --vla seems has no effect because it still complain that expression must has a constant value when I define a variable array         uint8_t Data[DataLen];

Comment: You have C99 in your project settings but do you have IAR extensions? The C99 standard allows anonymous structures but the IAR compiler reference manual says that anonymous structures are a C++ feature and are only allowed for C projects with extensions enabled. Perhaps that is the problem.

Comment: My device is a cortex-m0 core device named nuc100 from Winbond. tinman saied perhaps a extension is needed. I will try to find it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of your second question that code is invalid because what you have is a void * and you are trying to increment it by sizeof(uint8_t) (I assume 1). That is equivalent to:

```
void *p;
p += 1;
```

You cannot perform pointer arithmatic on a pointer which has an incomplete type because the compiler does not know how the value to increment by (remember it goes by the size of the object pointed to).

You probably meant to cast the pointer to a uint8_t pointer before incrementing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. OK,I've understand your answer.But another question is why gcc can compiler it through.

Comment: Perhaps there is a gcc extension that automatically assumes you mean to add in byte increments if you add values to void pointer? Sorry, I don't know for sure as I don't use gcc.

Comment: GCC does have such an extension: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith

Comment: Always compile GCC with -std=c99 -pedantic. Or it might decide to do weird GCC extension things with your program.

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifdef I_JUST_LOVE_MYSTERIOUS_COMPILER_ERRORS
  struct 
  {
    uint16_t ConnectionHandle;
    uint8_t  Reason;
  }DisconnectParams;
#else
  typedef struct 
  {
    uint16_t ConnectionHandle;
    uint8_t  Reason;
  }DisconnectParams_t;

  DisconnectParams_t DisconnectParams;
#endif
```

Comment: Does this actually help?  If so I can't understand why - how can the compiler accept the address of a type as an argument to a function call?  How can it even evaluation it?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I have no idea, there is too little info to tell. It seems like one of the likely issues though. Give it a try.

Comment: @lundin - it won't work: `struct {...} DisconnectParams` defines a nameless struct and declares a variable (named DisconnectParams) of that type in one go; `typedef struct {...} DisconnectParams` defines a nameless struct and declares a synonym for that type (named DisconnectParams).  DisconnectParams in the first case is a variable, in the second a type.  In the second case the call to `Bluetooth_HCI_SendControlPacket` with `&DisconnectParams` will definitely be a compiler error...

Comment: @Attila I suspect that the OP is intelligent enough to figure out another type name and declare DisconnectParams as a variable of that type.

Comment: Nevertheless, you might want to update your answer.  It won't take long :)

Comment: @Attila Ok since you insist. Updated.